# Multiply values from different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, aggregate-functions

So I am working on expanding a database for a school project. It is for a fictional company which delivers ingredients for recipes to you with instructions on how to make it and so on (like HelloFresh).

I have two tables from which I want to multiply values: a "recipe_ingredients" table and an "ingredient" table.

```
CREATE TABLE RECIPE_INGREDIENTS(
    RECIPEID            INTEGER NOT NULL,
    INGREDIENTID        INTEGER NOT NULL,
    AMOUNT              INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE INGREDIENT(
    INGREDIENTID    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    .
    .
    CALORIES        INTEGER,
);
```

I want to multiply the calories from the ingredient table with the amount from the recipe_ingredients table in order to be able to SUM() the calories and filter out the recipes that exceed a certain amount of calories later on.

I have tried this to multiply them:

```
SELECT CALORIES, AMOUNT,(CALORIES*AMOUNT) AS TEST
FROM INGREDIENT,
     RECIPE_INGREDIENTS;
```

but as you probably can guess, I now have every single calorie amount multiplied with every amount I wrote down.

What I want to happen is that only the ingredients that are listed with its ID in the recipe_ingredient table have their calories multiplied with their amount that I wrote in the recipe_ingredients table.
How can I do that?

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (**without errors**), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed

Comment: You must set matching condition between RECIPE_INGREDIENTS row and INGREDIENT. Now you attach any row to any even if ingredients in the rows differs. And you must to define in what group do you want to calculate calories (per a recipe?).

Comment: Note that recipes sometimes include the same ingredient twice, so it might not make sense to form a PK on (recipe,ingredient)

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

So you need to use both a join and an extra column to specify this as the ingredient and amount are no unique

i would suggest

```
Select
RecipeID
,Amount
,(i.Calories*Amount) as test
from RECIPE_INGREDIENTS r
inner
Join INGREDIENT i
on i.INGREDIENTID = r.INGREDIENTID
```

This will then show the calories for each recipe ingredient

Comment: You could also add a  condition to check the number of calories  and then just do equi- join as you did